# Trigger not working in .exe program which uses embedded derby database

Tags: java, triggers, exe, derby

I downloaded a windows application (.exe) that uses an embeded Derby database. I want to detect when the application adds a new recor in a table named INCIDENCIAS and then call for a Java method. To do that I created a trigger in that table and tested it succefully by adding records to the table (with DBVisualizer connected to the databse).

My problem is that at the moment I configure the trigger in INCIDENCIAS table the .exe application do not add more records to the database and the trigger does not work (it is not calling the Java method).

Is there any way to troubleshoot the problem? Any hints on what the problem can be?

Comment: Hints on what the problem can be are found here: (1) derby.log output, (2) exceptions returned to your program, (3) your program's source code itself. You can increase the logging level of Derby to get more information in the derby.log output.

Comment: Thanks. I am using embedded derby, not server. I can't find derby.log file, in derby documentation I understand it is only updated in server mode.

Comment: on the (2) and (3) I only have the executable I don't have the code. I believe the App is written in java and packaged in windows .exe. I am just integration another application that I wrote in Java through the derby database by introducing a trigger.

Comment: Ouch. Sounds like whoever has given you this application has deliberately made it fairly self-contained, and hard to peek inside. Can you contact that provider and ask them for help?

Comment: I can’t find contact info, unfortunately.